# how do you inject a bean into a @Controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm somewhat new to Spring (using 3.0), so I'm hoping there is a simple answer.  If I have a controller that is annotated with `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` and I want to set a property via dependency injection, how do I go about doing that?  The controller class doesn't have to appear in the Spring configuration file because it gets picked up automatically because of the `@Controller` annotation.

Example Controller class:

```
package gov.wi.dnr.wh.web.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class RehabHomeController {
  private String xxx;

  @RequestMapping(value="/rehab/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String get() {
    return "whdb.rehabhome";
  }

  public String getXxx() {
    return xxx;
  }

  public void setXxx(String xxx) {
    this.xxx = xxx;
  }
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>

  <context:component-scan base-package="gov.wi.dnr.wh.web.spring"/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

This works as is, but I would like to inject the "xxx" property.  How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
@Autowired
private YourService yourServiceBean;
```

(you can also use `@Inject`)

Of course, `YourService` has to be declared as a bean - either in `applicationContext.xml`, or by annotations (`@Service` for example)

If you want to inject string properties, you can use the `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("${propName}")
private String str;
```

(For that you will need a [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html))

Comment: Thanks.  How would it look in the applicationContext.xml file if I simply wanted to inject a String with a value of "hello"?

Comment: Hi can anybody tell me how can we do it without autowiring, basically i do not want my variable name to be dependent on the bean.

Comment: does it work if the service is defined in mvc-config.xml? I'm trying to inject bean defined in mvc-config.xml in a component class, it's not working.